# Adding an interface to a Dart extention method

Tags: dart, interface, extension-methods

Is it possible to add an interface to a Dart extension? In Swift you can do this:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
  associatedtype Item
  mutating func nextItem() -> Item?
}

extension MyClass: MyProtocol {

  public typealias Item = T

  public mutating func nextItem() -> T? {
    // ...
  }
}
```

How do you do that in Dart? It seems this is not possible:

```dart
extension MyClassExtension<T> on MyClass implements MyInterface {
  T? nextItem() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible. Swift protocols are more like (Rust-like) traits, that allows dynamic dispatch on the protocol implementation. Dart does not have this, and Dart extensions are never dynamically dispatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to add an interface to a Dart extension. See the discussion here:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/475
- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/736

You have to manually add the methods from the interface as you would a normal extension method:

```dart
extension MyClassExtension<T> on MyClass<T> {
  T? nextItem() {
    // ...
  }
}
```